# Remote selenium server for protractor

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

How to setup a remote webdriver-manager for protractor? If i change seleniumAddress in conf to 'http://remoteAddressInLan:4444/wd/hub', it opens browser in remote machine, but i want it in my local. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `seleniumAddress` config altogether, that should launch it locally
So you'll have:

```
exports.config = {
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```

instead of:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js']
};
```